# How to compare nesting structures?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I wanna compare two nesting structures, like comparing `[[[1],[2],[3]],[2],3]` with `[1,'a',[[[1]],['abc','d']]]`. How can that be done?

Comment: Define `compare`. Do you want to see if they are equal? What are you `comparing`, the lists, the list of lists, or the ACTUAL value way down in the list? Are you always sure they are the same size? etc. We need more information please =)

Comment: I'm comparing the structure of the list, not the values

Comment: Define `structure`. Number of items? Dimensions? Data within (str, int, etc). What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, it seems like neither the types nor count of elements within the lists matters, but only the "nesting-structure" of the lists themselves. Thus, you could just recursivly remove everything from the lists that is not another nested list, then compare what's left.

```
def purge(lst): 
    return [purge(x) for x in lst if isinstance(x, list)] 

a = [[[1],[2],[3]],[2],3]                                               
b = [1,'a',[[[1]],['abc','d']]]                                         
purge(a)                                                                
# [[[], [], []], []]
purge(b)                                                                
# [[[[]], []]]
purge(a) == purge(b)                                                    
# False
```

Feel free to extend this to other structures, like `dict` and `set`.

If types do matter, but not counts, you could use this variant, that will keep the `type` of each on-list item, but collapse same conscutive entries (note how this also collapses `[7],[8],[9]` to just `[int]`, other than the first version):

```
import itertools

def purge2(lst):
    tmp = [purge2(x) if isinstance(x, list) else type(x).__name__ for x in lst]
    return [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(tmp)]

c = [[[1,2,3],["a","b"],4,[5,6]],[7],[8],[9]]
purge2(c)
# [[['int'], ['str'], 'int', ['int']], ['int']]
```

Note that this way you can not directly compare the "purged" lists, at least not if an empty list should match a list with any contents. For this you will need another recursive compare method.

---

Conversely, you could also define a function that *keeps* everything but the list structure, maybe you can use this, too, for some other comparison...

```
def leafs(lst): 
    return [x for y in lst 
              for x in (leafs(y) if isinstance(y, list) else [y])] 

leafs(a)                                                               
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
leafs(b)                                                               
# [1, 'a', 1, 'abc', 'd']
```

Comment: If you have lists like a = [[[1],[2],[3]],'a',[2]] , b = [[[1],[1],[1]],[0]] it will not give the correct results with purge function

Comment: @ncica So, you know what the "correct" result for this case should be?

Comment: for a = [[[1],[2],[3]],'a',[2]] , b = [[[1],[1],[1]],[0]], purge(a)==purge(b) will gave True, I think the original data does not have the same structure?

Comment: @ncica I know what my code does. Why do you think it is false? What is your exact interpretation? Mine seems to be different, but might be wrong (or yours).

Comment: in the end I think that OP did not clearly define what he wont, I apologize if I made a mistake :)  I noticed your code because the solution seemed good and clean :)

Comment: @ncica You might have been right though. On closer inspection, OP said something about comparing types in comments. See my update.

Comment: @tobias_k , Sorry, if I provided less information or misleading information. But, What output I expect is just the comparison of way lists and other elements are arranged inside. I'm just a beginner, so it's a bit hard for me to explain what I want... :)

Comment: @tobias_k I actually just wanted to get the output as the nesting structure of lists. Using purge for examples [ 1 , [ 1 , 1 ] ] and [ [ 1 , 1 ] , 1 ], this comparison returned True, But it was actually False, So I edited the code, as shown below and got the right answer. I apologize, for I didn't know exactly how to explain that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following function achieves your desired results by comparing the size of the lists:

```
def compare_struc(arr1, arr2):
    len1 = len(arr1)
    len2 = len(arr2)

    if len1 == len2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    testlist1 =  [[1],[2],[3]]
    testlist2 = [[],[],[]]

    answer = compare_struc(testlist1, testlist2)

    print("The answer was: ", answer)

main()
```

> Outputs:
>
> The answer was:  True

Comment: Can you generalize this for any list comparison please? :). Like a list has one int and another has a list of lists all the way down?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the question what exactly is the criteria to determine if two structures are equivalent. [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114706/1782792) is a reasonable guess, here is another. I take that an item is a "leaf" if it is not a list or if it is a list but it does not contain more lists. With this we could have this:

```
def is_leaf(s):
    return not (isinstance(s, list) and any(isinstance(i, list) for i in s))

def have_similar_structure(s1, s2):
    if is_leaf(s1):
        return is_leaf(s2)
    elif is_leaf(s2):
        return False
    # Both are non-leaf
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    return all(have_similar_structure(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in zip(s1, s2))

print(have_similar_structure([[[1], [2], [3]], [2], 3], [[[], [], []], [], None]))
# True
print(have_similar_structure([[]], [1, 2, [3]]))
# False
print(have_similar_structure([[]], [1]))
# False
```